# Drawing half-circles with CoreGraphics

Tags: ios, drawing, core-graphics

I know how to draw lines and shapes with `CGPath`s . But I couldn't figure out how to draw this symbol for a circuit diagram

What code should I write to get that half circle shape?

This is what I have so far:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 60, 80);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 120, 80);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 120, 80);
    CGContextAddArc(120,80,M_PI,M_PI/2);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 200, 80);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 300, 80);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

Comment: Are you using CoreGraphics for drawing? Please share some code so that we can have some idea.

Comment: Hi, please do not delete questions that others have put a *lot* of energy in answering. It's incredibly selfish and against the spirit these sites are operated in.

Answer (score 6):

You could create a `UIBezierPath`, e.g. something like:

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
CGPoint point = CGPointMake(0, 50);
CGFloat radius = 15.0;
CGFloat lineLength = 25.0;

[path moveToPoint:point];
point.x += lineLength;
[path addLineToPoint:point];
point.x += radius;
[path addArcWithCenter:point radius:radius startAngle:M_PI endAngle:M_PI * 2 clockwise:YES];
point.x += radius * 2;
[path addArcWithCenter:point radius:radius startAngle:M_PI endAngle:M_PI * 2 clockwise:YES];
point.x += radius * 2;
[path addArcWithCenter:point radius:radius startAngle:M_PI endAngle:M_PI * 2 clockwise:YES];
point.x += radius * 2;
[path addArcWithCenter:point radius:radius startAngle:M_PI endAngle:M_PI * 2 clockwise:YES];
point.x += lineLength + radius;
[path addLineToPoint:point];
```

You could have your view controller just create a `CAShapeLayer` and add it to your view's `layer`.

```
CAShapeLayer *layer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
layer.path = [path CGPath];
layer.lineWidth = 2.0;
layer.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
layer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];

[self.view.layer addSublayer:layer];
```

If you wanted to do it in the `drawRect` of a `UIView` subclass you could, `stroke` this path:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    CGPoint point = CGPointMake(0, 50);
    CGFloat radius = 20.0;
    CGFloat lineLength = 45.0;

    [path moveToPoint:point];
    point.x += lineLength;
    [path addLineToPoint:point];
    point.x += radius;
    [path addArcWithCenter:point radius:radius startAngle:M_PI endAngle:M_PI * 2.0 clockwise:YES];
    point.x += radius * 2.0;
    [path addArcWithCenter:point radius:radius startAngle:M_PI endAngle:M_PI * 2.0 clockwise:YES];
    point.x += radius * 2.0;
    [path addArcWithCenter:point radius:radius startAngle:M_PI endAngle:M_PI * 2.0 clockwise:YES];
    point.x += radius * 2.0;
    [path addArcWithCenter:point radius:radius startAngle:M_PI endAngle:M_PI * 2.0 clockwise:YES];
    point.x += lineLength + radius;
    [path addLineToPoint:point];

    path.lineWidth = 2.0;
    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
    [[UIColor clearColor] setFill];

    [path stroke];
}
```

Or, as your revised question suggests, if you're more comfortable with CoreGraphics, you could do that, too:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGPoint point = CGPointMake(0, 50);
    CGFloat radius = 20.0;
    CGFloat lineLength = 45.0;

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, point.x, point.y);
    point.x += lineLength;
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, point.x, point.y);
    point.x += radius;
    CGContextAddArc(context, point.x, point.y, radius, M_PI, M_PI * 2.0, NO);
    point.x += radius * 2.0;
    CGContextAddArc(context, point.x, point.y, radius, M_PI, M_PI * 2.0, NO);
    point.x += radius * 2.0;
    CGContextAddArc(context, point.x, point.y, radius, M_PI, M_PI * 2.0, NO);
    point.x += radius * 2.0;
    CGContextAddArc(context, point.x, point.y, radius, M_PI, M_PI * 2.0, NO);
    point.x += lineLength + radius;
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, point.x, point.y);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);

    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);
}
```

Comment: oh thats great :) thanks alot . I just want to make sure of something , isn't there a simpler way where i can just add 2 or three lines to my code ? thanks for your help

Comment: @user2988343 You're just doing two lines of code (`CGContextAddArc` and adjusting the `point`) for each hump. You could do `for` loop if you want...